# How do IIS and asp.net core work together to prevent race conditions?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, concurrency, thread-safety, webserver

If I have an asp.net core app hosted in IIS and 5000 users make a request to login at the same time and then proceed to all download a document linked to their unique user id, how do their requests not cause a race condition? Does each request run it's own version of the code?

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core application concurrency is handled by its web server, So they will not compete. For example, you could configure IIS application pool in web.config or in aspnet.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <applicationPool
        maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="5000"
        maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0"
        requestQueueLimit="5000" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If 5000 concurrent requests request IIS at the same time, IIS will not start 5000 threads to process these requests at the same time. In win7, IIS will start 10 worker threads to process, then the other 4990 requests must be queued. Queuing is for the user experience The web page is loading, but nothing is displayed.

Comment: so, for those 10 worker threads, do they each get their own dll to execute? if I were to set multiple breakpoints in a method, and all the requests went to that method, how would they not affect each other's variable values? Does that make sense?

Comment: These work processes do not affect each other. You can refer to this document about how IIS handles http requests: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture

Comment: Hey Ding, my understanding of threading was insufficient. now that I understand how threads work when executing code, I understand your answer

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how threads work in regards to executing the code after a request is received?